# TableView.DeselectRow not triggering Deselected event for custom Element

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I may be missing something here, however, I can't get the `Deselect` event to trigger on my custom `Element` class when I manually deselect a row. I am overriding the cell to do some custom drawing and I want to change the colour of the font when the cell is selected/deselected.

A working example of the actual issue is detailed below.

```
public class TestViewController : DialogViewController
{
    public TestViewController () : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain, null, true)
    {
        Root = new RootElement(null);
        var section = new Section();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var element = new MyCustomElement();
            element.Tapped += (dvc, tableView, indexPath) => {
                var sheet = new UIActionSheet("", null, "Cancel", null, null);
                sheet.Dismissed += delegate(object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e) {                   
                    tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, false);
                };
                sheet.ShowInView(View);
            };
            section.Add (element);
        }
        Root.Add (section);
    }
}

public class MyCustomElement : Element, IElementSizing {
    static NSString mKey = new NSString ("MyCustomElement");

    public MyCustomElement () : base ("")
    {
    }

    public MyCustomElement (Action<DialogViewController,UITableView,NSIndexPath> tapped) : base ("")
    {
        Tapped += tapped;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell (mKey);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, mKey);
        return cell;
    }

    public float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 65;
    }

    public event Action<DialogViewController, UITableView, NSIndexPath> Tapped;

    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected!");
        if (Tapped != null)
            Tapped (dvc, tableView, path);
    }

    public override void Deselected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        // does not trigger when deselect manually invoked
        Console.WriteLine("Deselected!");
        base.Deselected (dvc, tableView, path);
    }
}
```

I have also tried overriding the `Deselected` event on the `DialogViewController` itself and even creating a custom `Source` and overriding the `RowDeselected` event in there but it's still not triggered. The only way I get it to trigger is if I remove the `Tapped` handler and select a different cell.

To get around the issue what I am doing at the moment is manually forcing the element to update itself after I call `DeselectRow`, however, I would like to know *why* it's not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

you not receive Deselected event because deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: method does not cause the delegate to receive a tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor will it send UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers and calling this method does not cause any scrolling to the deselected row.

Comment: Appears a bit of a limitation then don't you think? As you can see from the example shown there are obvious examples where you would want to deselect an item in a list view manually. Is there another way to deselect an item in the list that *will* send the notification?

Comment: its ios limitation, not monotouchdialog. When appears tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: monotouch dialog called deselected event for target element, but when you called tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, false) tablesource not receive tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: and deselected event not called. you can make function which removes the selection and calls the deselect event for element.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "*when appears tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: monotouch dialog called deselected event for target element*"? `DeselectRow` calls the native `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` behind the scenes.